# How to know files that `rsync --update` won't sync?

Tags: rsync

Is there any way to know what files haven't been synced by `rsync --update`?

I'd like to show these filenames in the terminal or, even better, redirect them to a text file.

Answer (score 2):

I answer myself: using the option `-vv` and `grep`, like this:

```
rsync --vv --update [maybe other options] dirA dirB | grep newer > newer_files.txt
```

Option `-vv` will tell you which files aren't being updated, reporting them on the terminal as `foofile is newer`.

Comment: Minor detail: option `--info=skip` is sharper than increasing the verbosity to level 2 with `-vv`. Option info was added in rsync 3.1.0 (Sept 2013). For the reference, see `rsync --info=help` about which type of messages are associated with each verbosity level.